# User-defined function returns non-formattable dates Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created a UDF in Excel VBA that returns an multi-dimensional array of dates and doubles. The problem is that I cannot format the dates that are returned.

Here is a simplified example:

```
Function test(dates as Range)
    Dim results
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim results(1 To dates.Cells.Count)
    For i = 1 To dates.Cells.Count
        results(i) = dates.Cells(i).Value
    Next
    test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results)
End Function
```

The transpose at the end is just for convenience to have an column output (I press Ctrl+Shift+enter). I you use this simplified example, you will not be able to format the output and it will not be considered as dates stricto sensu.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, just make sure your output cells are formatted as date or *General*

Comment: @CallumDA for me it returns strings that cannot be reformatted

Comment: @ScottCraner :O I see now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the results array to doubles:

```
Function test(dates As Range)
    Dim results() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim results(1 To dates.Cells.Count)
    For i = 1 To dates.Cells.Count
        results(i) = dates.Cells(i).Value
    Next
    test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results)
End Function
```

Or change the `dates.Cells(i).Value` to `dates.Cells(i).Value2` which will return the double not the date string:

```
Function test(dates As Range)
    Dim results
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim results(1 To dates.Cells.Count)
    For i = 1 To dates.Cells.Count
        results(i) = dates.Cells(i).Value2
    Next
    test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results)
End Function
```

Then format the cells as you desire.

Comment: OK, thanks. I used the Value2 and it solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this.

```
Results(i) = CDate(dates.Cells(i).Value)
```